# What's the most efficient way to handle different classes in a hierarchy with some same properties

Tags: c#, .net, xml, binding, xsd

I have searched to see if there have already existed a question about this so my apologies if I missed it.

I have a complex class structure I have embedded in my code from bindings produced by running xsd.exe on an xml schema so I didn't create the structure but I am having to deal with it.

There are some properties within classes in the hierarchy that are duplicated. I can't post the actual code for confidentiality reasons but for example if I have a base class with 10 classes inheriting from it, 8 of which have a property within them called WidgetValue, how can I most efficiently deal with this?

At the moment I am thinking I will have to check for the type of each of the inheriting classes and then cast to each of them to access the WidgetValue property.

Is there a better way that I could approach this though?

Comment: Confidentiality doesn't prevent you from providing a simplified but concrete example.  Also, "efficiently" requires elaboration.  Time efficiency?  Space efficiency?  Development time efficiency?  Parsimony of expression?   Without further information, all we can do is abstractly suggest alternatives such as: (1) Live with the duplication; (2) hoist `WidgetValue` to base class but make it optional; (3) create an intermediate class for the 8 classes that do require `WidgetValue`.  Which of these would be more "efficient" for your purposes is unclear.

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer. I mean in terms of development time efficiency. And to a lesser extent how complicated the code would then get. Because there are numerous places in the classes where this sort of thing happens so whatever I end up doing I will have to do a lot. If I do 2 or 3 then I'll have to modify the classes which means doing this every time the XSD gets re-released. There also may be a problem here with the fact that I will need to eventually output in XML conforming to the schema and I don't want to break compatibility with that.

Comment: Don't manually modify it unless you need to. Otherwise it will be gone the next time you need to regenerate the classes for any reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out, you should not modify the generated classes, because if for any reason you need to regenerate them, you will also need to modify them agaim.

So, I would either:

- Use `dynamic`, or
- Use `Reflection`

But first of all, this is the model I used for my tests:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public string MainProp { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : MainClass
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }

    public string WidgetValue { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : MainClass
{
    public string SomeOtherProp { get; set; }

    public string WidgetValue { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC : MainClass
{
    public string AnotherProp { get; set; }

    public string WidgetValue { get; set; }
}

public class ClassD : MainClass
{
    public string Different { get; set; }
}
```

And that's how you can get the WidgetValue using `dynamic` or `Reflection`:

```
static void GetWidgetValue(MainClass obj)
    {
        Type[] typesThatHaveWidgetValue = new Type[] { typeof(ClassA), typeof(ClassB), typeof(ClassC) };

        if (typesThatHaveWidgetValue.Contains(obj.GetType()))
        {
            dynamic o = obj;
            Console.WriteLine(o.WidgetValue);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object don't have property 'WidgetValue'");
        }
    }

    static void GetWidgetValueWithReflection(MainClass obj)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        var widgetValueProp = type.GetProperty("WidgetValue");
        if (widgetValueProp != null)
        {
            var widgetValue = widgetValueProp.GetValue(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(widgetValue);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object don't have property 'WidgetValue'");
        }
    }
```

And that's how you test it:

```
var classA = new ClassA { WidgetValue = "The Value" };
        var classB = new ClassB { WidgetValue = "The Other Value" };
        var classD = new ClassD();

        GetWidgetValue(classA); // The Value
        GetWidgetValue(classB); // The Other Value
        GetWidgetValue(classD); // Object don't have property 'WidgetValue'

        GetWidgetValueWithReflection(classA); // The Value
        GetWidgetValueWithReflection(classB); // The Other Value
        GetWidgetValueWithReflection(classD); // Object don't have property 'WidgetValue'
```

Then you **avoid** doing something like:

```
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(ClassA))
{
    var classA = (ClassA)obj;
    Console.WriteLine(classA.WidgetValue);
}
else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(ClassB))
{
    var classB = (ClassB)obj;
    Console.WriteLine(classB.WidgetValue);
} ...
```

Comment: The reflection method has worked very well. Thank you for the steer. I have voted it up but I don't have enough point for it to count publicly at the moment!